# Android change Alarm sound

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, audio

So I have an Alarm application which sets alarms. I have a very simple Service AlarmReceiver to get the alarm and do some action :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends Service{

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        MediaPlayer MPRadio1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.radio3);
        MPRadio1.start();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Alarm received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
    }
```

Now I'm wondering how would I be able to change the notification sound from another Activity so the AlarmReceiver service knows which sound should be played when alarm is received? So user can choose lets say, 3 sounds with radiobuttons and which he chooses AlarmReceiver knows which to play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the user's preferences (the uris to the ringtones in your shared preferences) then when creating it use the value stored in the preferences to get the new value. You **should** always grab this value from the shared preferences when registering your alarm.

### Note:

Also you should use SoundPool instead of a MediaPlayer **AND** you should also use Notifications they way they were intended, to be sent to the Notification bar via a PendingIntent. This notification sounds like your your actual activity is doing it, which is not how Notification tones should work.